# Estimating duration of an event (in absence of extra information)

Tags: probability

My question is to estimate the time an event is going to last. To put it in concrete terms,
suppose that we have an event that starts at $t=0$, and that lasts until some
$t=T$ (unknown). We are now at time $t_0$; and we see the event is running during $[0,t_0]$. Can we estimate $T$? I.e. compute the expected value of the probability distribution $T$, knowing that $T\geq t_0$.

The key point of the question is the absence of extra information (including which is the probability distribution). One has to make a reasonably explainable model.

I have an answer as $E[T]=e\cdot t_0$. Has somebody seen something like this in the literature?

**Added: I have written a note with the answer. It is [here](https://www.ucm.es/vicente_munoz/books-and-divulgation) (article 31). It is a mathematical explanation of the Lindy effect**

Comment: I have little knowledge in statistics, however I would expect additional information in order to derive the result. There are cases where a result is independant of the distribution (e.g. central limit theorem), but here we have just one observation. Perhaps the reasoning is "without additional information, assume a Poisson distribution", as it is the distribution of independent events, so it could be (in an informal way) assumed as the best "zero-hypothesis" distribution. But then you probably need some hypothesis on distribution of $\lambda$ to conclude.

Comment: I know that I am being (purposely) quite vague. Otherwise, if I fix the distribution the problem would be easy. Let me give an example: species in nature have a duration in time, it can be some million years, it can be billion years, or just thousand years; I imagine some can be just few years. If I take a random species that has been on earth for $t_0$ years. Which distribution would you (reasonably) put for estimating $T$?

Comment: But then there is no answer, from a mathematical viewpoint. There are only domain-dependent answers, because each domain comes with its (possibly implicit) hypotheses. An example of another no-sensible-answer question: "If we take real numbers at random, what is the mean?". This requires additional hypotheses.